# Is there a tailored way to get into web application hacking- considering that I am a math PhD?

Tags: professional-education

I am a mathematician, I have a PhD, I am specialised in stochastic processes, finance, pricing and arbitrage theory, I have publications in Q1 journals, but still, I feel that I am missing something ...

Currently I work for academia as a researcher. However, I think I am interested in getting into security. I have always had a passion for algorithms and coding and solving riddles, and as a child I wanted to be a hacker.

Could you suggest any specific list of steps I should take to get closer to a job in this area?

Is it fine if I start with reading "The Web Application Hacker's Handbook"?

I am good at math, I can write and read code (lot of experience in python and some in c++), and I think I am good at learning.

Comment: This is a lot like asking "is there a tailored way to get into mathematics?" The tailored way is to take classes, read books, and practice. The same here.

Answer (score 0):

A PhD in math in general would be way overqualified to be busy with simple web application hacking in my opinion. However your skills could be a great asset specifically to the **field of cryptography**. The Cryptography site StackExchange might be a good starting point: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

If you in particular want to get started with Web Application Security, I would recommend starting to look at one of the many Open Web Application Security Project [OWASP](https://owasp.org/) projects. Such as the [OWASP Top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) or the [OWASP ASVS](https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/) project. Moreover is you're looking into educational options I think depending on your interests you could check out the Certified Information Systems Security Professional ([CISSP](https://www.isc2.org/Certifications/CISSP)) certification or Certified Ethical Hacker ([CEH](https://www.eccouncil.org/programs/certified-ethical-hacker-ceh/)) certification.

Moreover general knowledge of information technology, computer science might be helpful. You could start by diving into different programming languages (commonly used on the web) and their security specific up- and downsides, best practices, common vulnerabilities and risk et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

The question is opinions based and can be closed.

Nevertheless, I'd suggest you to work a few years as a software developer: Learn modern technologies, start from web applications, learn databases, distributed application, cloud technologies, understand concepts behind them and implementations. Now days there are many different frameworks that simplify the development a lot, but also hide a lot. Try to understand a few such frameworks.

Then you can understand what security problems can happen in the field of information processing. Then you will be able to design solutions that can prevent these problems.

Learn also how the processes in companies should be organized to provide the desired level of security.